# Android emulator not responding to media queries

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, adt

I´m developing a web app with Phonegap and ADT in Eclipse, and I want to test it in the emulator. However, my design looks exactly the same no matter which device I choose to emulate. I have a breakpoint on max-width 480, but devices bigger than this also render the page as if below 480. I have included the viewport metatag like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

and my media queries look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {...}
```

I have also tried

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:480px) {...}
```

and included vendor-specific resolution with the same result. Everything looks fine when I resize my browser window in Firefox or Chrome and in Chrome devTools emulator. Is this a problem in my ADT emulator and can I trust the result in Chrome devTools, so I can use this for testing instead?

Comment: ya u can use..try in mozilla by pressing ctrl+shft+m.. u can see different views from that u can test it.. can u post tour code